# How can I solve the memory problem that appears when you read the dataset?

Tags: pandas, low-memory

Regardless what you set `low_memory` , `true` or `false` I get the memory error.
Unable to allocate 13.5 GiB for an array with shape (4357, 415796) and data type float64

Comment: How large is the file you're trying to read, what format is it in?

Comment: read the dataframe in chunks

Comment: The format is CSV. The size 12,408,250 KB

Comment: Wait, your file has only 4k rows, but 415k columns??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`low_memory=True` only helps reduce memory usage while parsing, it won't help at all with the total size of the file.

To process a file this large you'll need to work on it in chunks.

If some of your calculations need the whole file at once, you'll need to look into other options such as `pyspark` or `dask`.

```
# IIUC, this should approx. be chunks of ~1.2GB:
with pd.read_csv('file.csv', chunksize=400) as reader:
    for chunk in reader:
        # Do stuff with each chunk.
```